# can't enable 3d accelaration in virtual box

Tags: 3d, hardware-acceleration

Running ubuntu 18 (latest release) on virtual box with windows 10 as host, I've tried unsucessfuly to enable 3d accleration.

-I've ticked the "enable 3d accleration" on display settings in virtual box
-installed guest additions

/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p still shows 3d acclearation as "NO"

virtual box version is 5.2.8
nvidia 930mx, asus laptop

Comment: "enable 3d accelaration in virtual box" : The first hit with Google is https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/3d-acceleration-for-ubuntu-guests-v2

Comment: as I mentioned I've already done that, still not 3d accleration